# FirebaseMessaging Android some messages are lost

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FirebaseMessaging in an Android Application for an instant messaging.

For messages from server to device Android, there is no loss of message.

But from mobile to server some messages are lost...

The server receives the ACK messages, but in the other direction (mobile to server) the mobile does not receive the ACK.

The consequence is that 30% approximately of messages are lost. If I send multiple messages quickly, there will be more loss (40-60%). If I send multiple message slowly, there are 10% lost messages...

When I send messages mobile to server, I noticed that in my FirebaseMessagingService, the method "onMessageSent" is called by vague of 10 messages. Is it normal ? 
Why "onMessageSent" is not called once as soon as message was sent...

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
/** constante pour renvoyer la position GPS */
public static final String BROADCAST_FIREBASE_FILTER= "android.intent.action.MY_APP_FIREBASE";

private DatabaseHelper helper;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Notification method below.       
    DebugLog.logw(TAG,"MESSAGE RECEIVED");
    String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();        
    [..]

}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody,Intent intent2) {

    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent2,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    super.onDeletedMessages();
    DebugLog.logi(TAG, "onDeletedMessages");
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
    DebugLog.logi(TAG, "onMessageSent = " + s);
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String s, Exception e) {
    super.onSendError(s, e);
    DebugLog.logi(TAG, "onSendError = " + s);
}
```

}

My method in my FragmentMessaging for send an message :

```
public void sendMessage(Message msg){
    DebugLog.logd("FragmentMessagerie","sendMessage msg = " + msg.getMsg());
    if(textMessage.getText().length()>0) {
        final Message message = msg;        

        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
        FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();

        RemoteMessage rm = new RemoteMessage.Builder(senderID)
                .setMessageId("myApp_" +  atomicInteger.incrementAndGet() + System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addData("action", "chat")
                .addData("destinataire", String.valueOf(contact.getId()))
                .addData("emetteur",username)
                .addData("texte",msg.getMsg())
                .setTtl(0)
                .build();                    
        fm.send(rm); // appel à fireBase pour l'envoi du message  
        [..]

        textMessage.setText("");
    } else {
        [..]
    }
}
```

}

My questions are :

When sending a message (firebaseMessaging.send(remoteMessage)) Firebase is supposed to handle the sending of messages to server.

Is it Android that sends the messages incorrectly to Firebase ?

Or is it Firebase that sends the messages badly to my server ?

On the server, I receive the ACK messages sent to mobiles.

On my device Android, I don't receive the ACK message, only the method "onMessageSent" was called 10 times when 10 messages were sent...  Is this normal ?

How can I receive ACK for messages device Android to server ? from my device ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says in [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream), that the response is batched.

> To optimize network usage, FCM batches responses to onMessageSent and 
>   onSendError, so the acknowledgement may not be immediate for each message.